# Is there is a way to add the color to that the part outside the rectangle and the body itself make it transparent (Using XML)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to exchange the pink part with the transparent part in the code

[forexample image to the shape I work on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3XAs.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid
    android:color="@color/primary_color"/>

<size
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp"/>

<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @ArchitGargi I want to make the transparent section in the image I provided in the link above with pink color and the pink section is transparent

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this using XML only.

You can solve in runtime by creating a Bitmap+Canvas, fill the Bitmap using appropriated color and then SUBTRACT the Drawable/Shape you linked as a Mask using PorterDuffXfermode.